# SQL Access problems from within Application Page

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint-Feature that connects to an SQL-Database. From within that (Site-)feature I can access the DBMS and even create a new Database without problems (using Linq2sql)

But inside the Application Page within the **SAME** Project I cannot even do a simple LinQ-Query on the just created Database.

I receive the error "

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

"

When debugging the code I can see that the credentials (SPWeb.CurrentUser) are both the same (and not anonymous at all)

The Feature Event Receiver as well as the Application Page use the same Connection String (with Integrated Security=true)

From other posts here I know that using an SQL-Login instead of integrated Security *might* help, but I am curious **why on the Event Receiver everything works perfect, but on the Application Page nothing works**?

Answer (score 0):

I've had that issue before and typically I can just run my SQL code in a `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges {` block and it works fine.

Forgive me for not getting the language/reason precisely correct, but I believe the reason it runs fine in your eventreceiver code is because that code is executed a in a different more trusted context than an application page.  Someone else might be able to explain more comprehensively/eloquently than me.

Comment: That changes the user to the application pools user, (svc_sp_crawl) which does not work in my case.

Comment: What type of authentication is being used on the Sharepoint server?